# What does library number 539 mean in physics books?

Tags: soft-question

Every book I borrow have have this number in them. Even my library categorizes them with this number. Is it a universal particle physics book number?

Comment: I am interested in opinions as to the topicality of this questions. I'm leaning toward off-topic myself, but I don't think we have ever discussed it.

Comment: This question isn't about Physics

Comment: @JohnRennie, well, it's a bit odd. To those who already know the answer, it's clearly not about physics. However, to someone who doesn't already know the answer, it's not inconceivable that a label consistently appearing in a set of physics books *could have* had some kind of physics-based significance. How do you treat a question that you can only identify with confidence as "not physics" if you already know the answer?

Comment: @dgh: I know the answer, and it isn't about physics. Arguing that it *might* have been about physics seems excessively philosophical. I'm not criticising Love Learning for asking the question, and you'll note I haven't downvoted. I'm just saying the question should be closed because it isn't about physics.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about library science.

Comment: Cases like this are so rare that I don't know if we really need a formal policy. We can just leave this here, on hold, and people will be able to find it, but it'll still show up as not being on topic.

Answer (score 7):

It's an identification number for a classification scheme called the [Dewey Decimal System](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dewey_Decimal_Classification). It's just a general system most libraries use for organizing books by subject matter; the numbers don't mean anything. 500 is the Dewey series for [science](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_Dewey_Decimal_classes#Class_500_.E2.80.93_Science), 530 is physics, and 539 is modern physics.

I don't know if this question is really appropriate for Physics.SE, but then, I don't know if any other SE would be.

Comment: Yeah, where do you post this question? I searched google, no answer no question. At least now it has been asked and answered somewhere (here).

Comment: I think it could be really useful to have a *physicists*.stackechange.com to ask questions that come up in the life of a physicist, but are not directly physics. Alternatively one could think about allowing them on meta.physics.stackexchange.com, which is right now only meta Q&A for the site itself.

Answer (score 2):

539.7 is the code for Atomic and nuclear physics books in the Dewey Decimal Classification system. For more informations about it, check the wikipedia article http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dewey_Decimal_Classification

Comment: Ahh yeah, our library just recently switched to these funny numbers, and then of course I started noticing these numbers in books, all over the place .

Comment: @LoveLearning, "just recently"? It seems surprising to me that a library would only _now_ start using the standard for library organization of nonfiction books. Is it an especially small library?

Comment: Perhaps they used it internally, but kept it hidden from our eyes.

Comment: How were you able to find books if they weren't labelled?

Comment: The books themselves where labelled (with name and number I think), but the shelves where labelled with names (e.g. PhysTheo something something) rather than these numbers (if I recall correctly).